# Are there alternative BIOS ROMs for the IBM 5162?

Tags: ibm

[This page](http://www.minuszerodegrees.net/5162/bios/5162_bios_revisions.htm) references a problem with the IBM 5162 BIOS where it will present an error during POST under some circumstances and that using a third-party BIOS was a workaround.

What other BIOS ROMs would work with a 5162 and how would I find them today?

Comment: [Alternative 5170 BIOSs](http://www.minuszerodegrees.net/bios/bios.htm) *might* work...